# Connecting two Stacked Aruba 2930M Switch with third one using LACP

Tags: fiber, trunk, hp, ieee-802.1ax, aruba

In the skit, I would like to connect the two Stacked switches with a third one
using the SFPs+  Modules and therefore I need to configure the LACP for them.

How can I configure the LACP on both the Third Switch and the Stacked ones?

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A stack of 2 switches forms a single logical switch.

So you first configure the stack, without considering the third one.

You now have 2 switches (one stack and one standalone)

Then you create a Ling Aggregation Group (LAG) between the stack and the third switch, with a link from each stack member to the standalone switch.

Note: HP use the term "trunk" for a LAG while usually this term refer to a link carrying several VLAN (and I profoundly hate them for that).

I am no ARUBA expert but from [this documentation](https://support.hpe.com/hpesc/public/docDisplay?docId=a00107096en_us) you configure the interfaces in LACP active mode with the command

```
switch(config)# int c1-c4 lacp active
```

The documentation is sparse about it though. Hope some other people can help you with more details about the config.

Comment: Yes exactly what I want to do, how can I make the LAG between the stack and the third switch, please?

Comment: @Kikomi You can simply select ports across the stacking group (VSF) as LACP trunk members (e.g. `a1,b1-b2`). You might also want to consider integrating the 3rd switch into the stack.